# ActionBar Back button opens drawer instead of going back

Tags: java, android, android-actionbar, fragment

In my app I have problem like this. Note that I'm working with fragments and I have drawer too.

That's the method in my MainActivity for drawer open/close.

```
    public void drawerInit() {

    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar_actionbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer);
    view = findViewById(R.id.mainView);

    toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close) {

        @Override
        public void onDrawerSlide(View drawerView, float slideOffset) {
            super.onDrawerSlide(drawerView, slideOffset);
            float moveFactor = (drawerView.getWidth() * slideOffset);
            view.setTranslationX(moveFactor);
        }

        @Override
        public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
            super.onDrawerClosed(drawerView);
        }
    };

    drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();
}
```

Example I have 3 fragments (F1, F2, F3). F1 is my main fragment where I can open and close the drawer. When I'm opening F2 or F3 fragments, I need to change the drawer icon to back arrow. I'm doing this part successfully, but the problem is when I'm clicking on this back arrow, that opens the navigation drawer instead of going back. So how can I fix this part?

Here the part, where I'm changing the icon to back arrow in fragment.

```
((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().show();
((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
```

Answer (score 2):

**Add in your Activity**

```
    public void crateMenuButton(){
        toggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(true);
        if(toolbarDrawable == null) {
            toolbarDrawable = toolbar.getNavigationIcon();
        }
        toolbar.setNavigationIcon(toolbarDrawable);
        invalidateOptionsMenu();
        toggle.syncState();
    }

    public void createBackButton() {
        toggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(false);
        toggle.setToolbarNavigationClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //if the drawerToggle is disabled, fall off to the home button action
                if (!toggle.isDrawerIndicatorEnabled()) {
                    // pop fragment here
                    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
                    if (fragmentManager.getBackStackEntryCount() > 0) {
                        fragmentManager.popBackStack();
                    }
                } else {
                    if (drawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(navigationView)) {
                        drawerLayout.closeDrawer(navigationView);
                    } else {
                        drawerLayout.openDrawer(navigationView);
                    }
                }
            }
        });
        toolbar.setNavigationIcon(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_arrow_back_white));
    }
```

Download [Back Arrow](https://material.io/icons/#ic_arrow_back)

**Then call from your fragment as your need**

```
((YourActivity) getActivity()).createBackButton();
OR
((YourActivity) getActivity()).crateMenuButton();
```

Comment: that code didn't work for me, maybe because I had override `onOptionsItemSelected`. That is why i paste everything in `toogle.setToolbarNavigationClickListener` to my `onOptionsItemSelected`